# Rotating tablular CSV data with list comprehensions

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm newbishly hacking a tool that will help me collect data in this form: **[{Entity: {Field:Value}}, ...]**

Unless clue-sticked otherwise, this is how I'll express the data:

```
alldata = [
    {'ShinyCorp, Inc.' :
        [
        {'state' : 'CA'},
        {'phone' : '123-456-7890'}
        ]
    },

    {'MultiBiz, LLC' :
        [
        {'state' : 'NY'},
        {'ceo' : 'Glenn Suggzass'}
        ]
    },

    {'Marx Capital Group' : 
        [
        {'state' : 'DE'},
        {'fax' : '321-654-0987'}
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to present the data in two forms:

1) A list of **entity** names as the first column, with the columns of each row showing the field-value for the entity listed in the first **column** of this **row**

2) A list of **field** names as the first column, with the columns of each row showing the field-value for the entity listed in the first **row** of this **column** (aka the header)

Like so...

1)

```
EntityName          state   phone           ceo             fax
ShinyCorp, Inc.     CA      123-456-7890
MultiBiz, LLC       NY                      Glenn Suggzass
Marx Capital Group  DE                                      321-654-0987
```

2)

```
FieldName   ShinyCorp, Inc. MultiBiz, LLC   Marx Capital Group
state       CA              NY              DE
phone       123-456-7890
ceo                         Glenn Suggzass
fax                                         321-654-0987
```

So,...

Given the format of alldata (a list of EntityName-ordiented dicts), what are the list comprehensions that give DictWriter and writerows the iterables to write format 1) and 2).

EDIT: This is just a toy example for the purposes of getting some good list comprehension advice.

Comment: Why `[{'state': 'CA'}, {'phone': '123-456-7890'}]` and not `{'state': 'CA', 'phone': '123-456-7890'}`?  (Similarly for one level up, but you might have two rows of company information, I guess.)

Comment: Good question.  The tool is intended to gradually collate and organize small, far-flung internet info-bits into well-organized structures like you describe.  That's why the data is expressed in such a rudimentary way (entity:key:value).

Answer (score 0):

Very old question and very few chances that you are still around, but the question is interesting.

## A simpler data structure

First of all, I think your data structure is not the best. Let's say you get tuples like that (from a csv file):

```
>>> csv = [('ShinyCorp, Inc.', 'state', 'CA'),
... ('ShinyCorp, Inc.', 'phone', '123-456-7890'),
... ('MultiBiz, LLC', 'state', 'NY'),
... ('MultiBiz, LLC', 'ceo', 'Glenn Suggzass'),
... ('Marx Capital Group', 'state', 'DE'),
... ('Marx Capital Group', 'fax', '321-654-0987')]
```

You have to list entities and fields and their relations. If you don't care about the order:

```
>>> data_by_entity = {}
>>> fields = set()
>>> for entity,k,v in csv:
...     fields.add(k)
...     data_by_entity.setdefault(entity, {})[k] = v
...
>>> data_by_entity
{'ShinyCorp, Inc.': {'state': 'CA', 'phone': '123-456-7890'}, 'MultiBiz, LLC': {'state': 'NY', 'ceo': 'Glenn Suggzass'}, 'Marx Capital Group': {'state': 'DE', 'fax': '321-654-0987'}}
>>> sorted(fields)
['ceo', 'fax', 'phone', 'state']
>>> sorted(data_by_entity.keys())
['Marx Capital Group', 'MultiBiz, LLC', 'ShinyCorp, Inc.']
```

If you care about the order:

```
>>> data_by_entity = {}
>>> fseen = set()
>>> fields = []
>>> eseen = set()
>>> entities = []
>>> for entity,k,v in csv:
...     if entity not in eseen:
...         entities.append(entity)
...         data_by_entity[entity] = {}
...         eseen.add(entity)
...     if k not in fseen:
...         fields.append(k)
...         fseen.add(k)
...     data_by_entity[entity][k]=v
...
>>> data_by_entity
{'ShinyCorp, Inc.': {'state': 'CA', 'phone': '123-456-7890'}, 'MultiBiz, LLC': {'state': 'NY', 'ceo': 'Glenn Suggzass'}, 'Marx Capital Group': {'state': 'DE', 'fax': '321-654-0987'}}
>>> fields
['state', 'phone', 'ceo', 'fax']
>>> entities
['ShinyCorp, Inc.', 'MultiBiz, LLC', 'Marx Capital Group']
```

The `seen` trick keeps a set of the elements of the list. An element is added if (and only if) it is not in the list, that is... not in the set (O(1) vs 0(n) speed).

This data structure may be easily updated : give a new tuple to the body of the loop.

## From your data structure to the simpler data structure

```
>>> alldata = [
...     {'ShinyCorp, Inc.' :
...         [
...         {'state' : 'CA'},
...         {'phone' : '123-456-7890'}
...         ]
...     },
...
...     {'MultiBiz, LLC' :
...         [
...         {'state' : 'NY'},
...         {'ceo' : 'Glenn Suggzass'}
...         ]
...     },
...
...     {'Marx Capital Group' :
...         [
...         {'state' : 'DE'},
...         {'fax' : '321-654-0987'}
...         ]
...     }
... ]    

>>> data_by_entity = {e:{k:v for value in values for k,v in value.items()} for data in alldata for e, values in data.items()}
>>> data_by_entity
{'ShinyCorp, Inc.': {'state': 'CA', 'phone': '123-456-7890'}, 'MultiBiz, LLC': {'state': 'NY', 'ceo': 'Glenn Suggzass'}, 'Marx Capital Group': {'state': 'DE', 'fax': '321-654-0987'}}
```

Explanation:

- `for data in alldata`:  this is the outer dicts
- `for e, values in data.items()`: entity and list of inner dicts
- `{k:v for value in values for k,v in value.items()}`: this merges the inner dicts present in the list `values`.

It may be easier to understand with a `merge_list_of_dicts` function:

```
>>> def merge_list_of_dicts(L): return {k: v for d in L for k,v in d.items()}
>>> data_by_entity = {e:merge_list_of_dicts(values) for e, values in merge_list_of_dicts(alldata).items()}
>>> data_by_entity
{'ShinyCorp, Inc.': {'state': 'CA', 'phone': '123-456-7890'}, 'MultiBiz, LLC': {'state': 'NY', 'ceo': 'Glenn Suggzass'}, 'Marx Capital Group': {'state': 'DE', 'fax': '321-654-0987'}}
```

Getting the fields from the structure is easy:

```
>>> fields = set(k for data in data_by_entity.values() for k,v in data.items())
>>> sorted(fields)
['ceo', 'fax', 'phone', 'state']
```

## The output

Now, the answer to the question.

### 1st form

```
>>> fields = sorted(fields) # ensure the test is reproducible
>>> [["EntityName"]+fields]+[[k]+[v.get(f, "") for f in fields] for k, v in data_by_entity.items()]
[['EntityName', 'ceo', 'fax', 'phone', 'state'], ['ShinyCorp, Inc.', '', '', '123-456-7890', 'CA'], ['MultiBiz, LLC', 'Glenn Suggzass', '', '', 'NY'], ['Marx Capital Group', '', '321-654-0987', '', 'DE']]
```

Explanation:

- `["EntityName"]+fields]` is the first line;
- `[k]+[v.get(f, "") for f in fields]` iterate over the fields and gets the values. It is preceeded by `k`, the name of the field;
- `[[k]+[...] for k, v in data_by_entity.items()]` repeats the list above for every entity.

### 2nd form

```
>>> [["FieldName"]+entities]+[[k]+[data_by_entity[e].get(k, "") for e in entities] for k in fields]
[['FieldName', 'ShinyCorp, Inc.', 'MultiBiz, LLC', 'Marx Capital Group'], ['ceo', '', 'Glenn Suggzass', ''], ['fax', '', '', '321-654-0987'], ['phone', '123-456-7890', '', ''], ['state', 'CA', 'NY', 'DE']]
```

Explanation:

- `["FieldName"]+entities]` is the first line;
- `[k]+[data_by_entity[e].get(k, "") for e in entities]` iterate over the entities and gets the values of the given `k`. It is preceeded by `k`, the name of the field;
- `[[k]+[...] for k in fields]` repeats the list above for every field.

Here's another version

```
>>> L = [["EntityName"]+list(fields)]+[[k]+[v.get(f, "") for f in fields] for k, v in data_by_entity.items()]
>>> list(zip(*L))
[('EntityName', 'ShinyCorp, Inc.', 'MultiBiz, LLC', 'Marx Capital Group'), ('ceo', '', 'Glenn Suggzass', ''), ('fax', '', '', '321-654-0987'), ('phone', '123-456-7890', '', ''), ('state', 'CA', 'NY', 'DE')]
```

Explanation: `list(zip(*L)` is the idiomatic way to transpose a list of lists. If `L = [L1, ..., Ln]`, `zip(*L)` unpacks the list to `zip(L1, ..., Ln)`. Then `zip` creates a tuple with the first element of every list, another tuple with the second element of every list, ... until it exhausts one of the lists.